# How to use async/await with Multiple Related Collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to wrap my head around using async/await with promises and mongoose references.

The code below almost works: the 3 posts get created and so do the comments for the first one, but **none of the comments for the third post get created**.

I'm assuming this is because I'm not putting the async/awaits in the right place, but I don't know how to organize the code so it works.

```
const seedData = [
  {
    title: 'Post 1',
    content: `beard sustainable Odd Future pour-over Pitchfork DIY fanny pack art party`,
    comments: [
      { content: 'comment1 1' },
      { content: 'comment1 2' },
      { content: 'comment1 3' }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Post 2',
    content: `flannel gentrify organic deep v PBR chia Williamsburg ethical`,
    comments: []
  },
  {
    title: 'Post 3',
    content: `bag normcore meggings hoodie polaroid gastropub fashion`,
    comments: [{ content: 'comment3 1' }, { content: 'comment3 2' }]
  }
];

async function createPostsAndComments() {
  let promises = [];

  // delete existing documents
  Post.remove(() => {});
  Comment.remove(() => {});

  // create three posts along with their comments
  seedData.forEach(async postData => {
    // create the post
    let post = new Post({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      title: postData.title,
      content: postData.content
    });

    // wait for the promise returned by `post.save`
    promises.push(
      post.save(error => {
        if (error) console.log(error.message);

        // create the comments of the current post
        postData.comments.forEach(async commentData => {
          const comment = new Comment({
            content: commentData.content,
            post: post._id
          });

          // wait for the promise from `comment.save`
          promises.push(
            comment.save(error => {
              if (error) console.log(error.message);
            })
          );
        });
      })
    );
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

async function initSeed() {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true });
  await createPostsAndComments();
  mongoose.connection.close();
}

initSeed();
```

In case it's useful, here are the schemas:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

exports.commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }, // TODO: what's this?
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);
exports.Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', exports.commentSchema);
```

---

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

exports.postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});
exports.Post = mongoose.model('Post', exports.postSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually `await` the async calls that return a promise. Like `.remove()` and `.save()` and basically every single interaction with the database. We can also make some things simpler with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
// <<-- You use async because there are "inner" awaits.
// Otherwise just return a promise
async function createPostsAndComments() {   
  let promises = [];

  // delete existing documents  <<-- This is actually async so "await"
  await Promise.all([Post,Comment].map(m => m.remove()));

  // create three posts along with their comments <<-- Not actually async
  seedData.forEach(postData => {
    // create the post
    let post = new Post({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      title: postData.title,
      content: postData.content
    });

    // wait for the promise returned by `post.save`   <<-- You mixed a callback here
    promises.push(post.save());
    // create the comments of the current post  // <<-- Again, not async
    postData.comments.forEach(commentData => {
      const comment = new Comment({
        content: commentData.content,
        post: post._id
      });
      // <<-- Removing the callback again
      promises.push(comment.save())
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

// Just write a closure that wraps the program. async allows inner await
(async function()  {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true }); // <-- Yep it's a Promise
    await createPostsAndComments();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
})();
```

Alternately just make the `.remove()` calls part of the `promises` array as well, and now there is not need for `async/await` within that function. It's just promises anyway:

```
function createPostsAndComments() {   
  let promises = [];

  //await Promise.all([Post,Comment].map(m => m.remove()));
  promises = [Post,Comment].map(m => m.remove());

  // create three posts along with their comments <<-- Not actually async
  seedData.forEach(postData => {
    // create the post
    let post = new Post({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      title: postData.title,
      content: postData.content
    });

    // wait for the promise returned by `post.save`   <<-- You mixed a callback here
    promises.push(post.save());
    // create the comments of the current post  // <<-- Again, not async
    postData.comments.forEach(commentData => {
      const comment = new Comment({
        content: commentData.content,
        post: post._id
      });
      // <<-- Removing the callback again
      promises.push(comment.save())
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Or even just `await` everything instead of feeding to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
async function createPostsAndComments() {   

  await Promise.all([Post,Comment].map(m => m.remove()));

  for( let postData of seedData ) {
    // create the post
    let post = new Post({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      title: postData.title,
      content: postData.content
    });

    await post.save());

    for ( let commentData of postData.comments ) {
      const comment = new Comment({
        content: commentData.content,
        post: post._id
      });

      await comment.save())
    }
  }

}
```

Those seem to be the concepts you are missing.

Basically `async` is the keyword that means the "inner block" is going to use `await`. If you don't use `await` then you don't need to mark the block as `async`.

Then of course any "Promise" needs an `await` in place of any `.then()`. And just don't mix callbacks with Promises. If you really need to, then you can wrap callback style returns in a Promise, but your code here does not need them.

The other main consideration is "error handling". So all that we need do using `async/await` keywords is implement `try..catch` as is shown. This is preferable to `.catch()` in Promise syntax, and essentially defers all errors thrown from the "inner" function to the "outer" block and reports the error there.

So there is no need to add error handling "inside" the `createPostsAndComments()` function, since that function itself is called within a `try..catch`.

Comment: Thank you for that excellent response. I learned so much! I think I got confused because in the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), they create `story1` inside the `author.save` callback

Comment: I think `remove()` returns a `Query` not a promise, so I had to remove the `await` and also add an empty callback: `[Post, Comment].map(model => model.remove(() => {}));` Otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: @nachocab "Everything" returns a promise. This is code I run in production all of the time, and it's also a really common statement in answers of mine here, because it's a typical method for clearing collections on start for demonstrations. You're doing it wrong, I'm doing it right. That's the common theme of the answer you need to learn. If you have additional questions then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I know it's tempting to keep chatting to someone who answered a question, but you don't do that here.